# Gnome Documents unable to open documents!

Tags: gnome, 13.04, gnome-documents

I have an almost default install of Gnome Documents 3.6.2 on Gnome Shell 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 13.04.

When I open Gnome Documents, it opens the window with "New" and "Recent" documents showing. By clicking on any document, it just shows 'loading'.

What is missing? How do I set it right?

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have a /etc/mime.types file?
- Do you have a /usr/share/applications/defaults.list file?
- Do you have /usr/share/applications/...  .desktop files for every application that can open a document?
- Do you have /usr/share/mimelnk/application/libreoffice_... .desktop files? (if you use LibreOffice)
- Run

  ```
  sudo update-desktop-database
  ```
- In the right corner of GNOME Documents, there's an icon with a gear. If you click it wile laoding, you will see: Open document with...

Comment: A clarification. I open Gnome Documents. I see a Document window with New and Recent as title. I double-click on a file, the list goes away. I expect it to show the document. It just shows Loading animation. Is that how it is expected to workL

Comment: Can you check your evince version using your preferred package manager for me, that is, if you're using evince? As Frank said, when you see the loading indicator you should see a Settings/Gear icon on the top right, is this the case? Click it and tell us what you see for "Open with..."

Comment: I do see that gear. But that does not help. I thought it should show a preview after I click on the document. Also, the same is the case even with the Libreoffice documents.